# Why this clearInterval always work when function finished?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new in web programming and I'm learning javascript and jquery ajax now..

this is my javascript code. refresh variable is interval for refresh chat (get chats from database and showing them in the chat container) every 2secs. I want to stop the interval and then append a new message to the container after I submit the message.

the problem is when I pressed enter, new chat append to the container, yes. but suddenly the container is refreshed and replace that new message with records from database ( so it's gone (clearInterval is not working yet) ). Then clearInterval is working when function finished.. why? why? :(

```
var oldscrollHeight;
var newscrollHeight;
var refresh;
function refreshChats(){
  oldscrollHeight = $(".chatContainer").prop("scrollHeight");
  $.ajax({  
    url:"get_chats.php",  
    cache: false,  
    success: function(html){          
        $(".chatContainer").html(html);     

        //Auto-scroll             
        newscrollHeight = $(".chatContainer").prop("scrollHeight");  
        if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){  
            $(".chatContainer").prop({ scrollTop:         $(".chatContainer").prop("scrollHeight") });
       }                 
    }  
  });  
}

$("document").ready(function(){

  refresh = setInterval(refreshChats,2000);

  $(".chatValue").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && $(".chatValue").val() != ""){
        clearInterval(refresh);
        var me = $(".me").val();
        var chat = $(".chatValue").val();
        var time = $(".timeChat").val();
        $(".chatContainer").append(me+": "+chat+" ("+time+")"); //showing a new message before database updated
        $(".chatValue").val("");
        $.post("chat.php",{submitChat: true,chat: chat,time: time});
    } 
  });

});
```

Comment: Is `.chatValue` inside of a `form`? Is it an `input` or a `textarea`?

Comment: .chatValue is input type="text" without a form.. should it be inside a form?

Comment: If you only have an ajax chat then you don't need to place it in a `form`. I was asking because,  having an `input` element in a `form` is a common problem if you want to submit the data with the enter key using ajax only, because pressing enter will also cause the browser to submit the `form` the _regular_ way, which would result in your described behavior. So if it is not in a `form` then it is another problem, but it does not look like that it is part of the code you posted then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `refreshChats` performs Ajax.

When you clear the interval, you prevent `refreshChats` from running again.

If an HTTP request has **already been sent**, that won't prevent the event handler triggering when the HTTP response arrives, so the response will still be processed.

You need to set a flag to cancel the processing of the response (or to make the success handler abort without doing anything significant).